# SQL Server Query to show table name and specific column name and current value in all user table

Tags: sql-server

All of our user tables have a primary key and a `rowid_time` column. We would like to develop a SQL query which lists:

- table name
- the value of the primary key
- the value of the `rowid_time` column

(only these three columns and NOT ALL columns of the table)

for all rows and tables in the database.

Is that doable? Ideally this is delivered via a database view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display all data of all tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106108/display-all-data-of-all-tables)

Answer (score 0):

With dynamic SQL and using a [SQL cursor](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-cursor-example-tables-rows-count-using-sql-server-cursor.aspx), we can solve the requirement as follows

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @PKColumnList nvarchar(max)

DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT name FROM sys.tables order by Name 

OPEN mycursor

FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
----------------
    SELECT @PKColumnList = string_agg(COLUMN_NAME, ',')
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE a
    WHERE
     EXISTS(
      SELECT *
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS b
      WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND a.CONSTRAINT_NAME = b.CONSTRAINT_NAME) AND
     TABLE_NAME = @tablename

     SET @PKColumnList = concat(@PKColumnList+',','rowid_time')

    SELECT @SQL = '
;with t1 as (
    select ''' + @TableName + ''' as TableName
), t2 as (
    SELECT 
        ''' + @TableName + ''' as TableName, 
        COUNT(*) OVER (Partition By 1) as RowsCount, '
        + @PKColumnList +
'   FROM [' + @TableName + ']
)
select
    t1.TableName,
    t2.RowsCount, '
    + @PKColumnList + '
from t1
full join t2 
on t1.TableName = t2.TableName'

    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL

-----------------
  FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor INTO @TableName
END

CLOSE mycursor
DEALLOCATE mycursor
```

If the PK column for all tables is ID column (no composite key and all PK fields are named as ID for all tables), then [SQL sp_MSForEachTable](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-exec-sp_msforeachdb-sp_msforeachtable-example-tsql-code.aspx) procedure can be used as follows

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'SELECT ''?'' as TableName, ID, rowid_time FROM ?'
```